# HTML textbox only returning one word

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have a simple HTML template like this:

```
<html>
<head> Sentiment Analysis Dataset</head>
<form method='POST'>
    <b> Unclassified Text </b>
    <input type='text' name='Text' value={{db.Entry}} readonly><br>
</form>
</html>
```

And the following is my Flask code:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        db={'Entry':data.next()}
        print db
        return render_template('index.html', db=db)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        db={'Entry':data.next()}
        print db
        return render_template('index.html', db=db)
```

The db dictionary looks like `{'Entry': 'Worst thing I've ever seen'}`. When I run the app, it only shows the first word in the html textbox. Why does this happen? What can I do to show the entire string in the textbox?

Edit: I just wrapped {{db.Entry}} in quotes and it worked

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have no idea about Flask, however, what happens if you put quotes around the value of your html input?

e.g.

```
<input type='text' name='Text' value='{{db.Entry}}' readonly><br>
```

Comment: It's a jinja2 template, and it enables it to show dynamic data. So every time I submit a request, it will get populated by different data

Comment: I think you need to wrap {{db.Entry}} in quotes or the browser will see the words following the first as attributes.  "Inspect" your page and see what the browser is trying to render.